# В чем разница между аффиксацией и универбацией?

Tags: словообразование

Пишу реферат на тему молодежного жаргона, и меня интересует грань между некоторыми жаргонизмами, образованными с помощью аффиксации и универбации. Например: суффикс -ар- образует экспрессивные существительные с грубоватым оттенком: лох - лошара. С помощью аффикса -он- от основ глагола образуются такие слова, как «закусон» (закусить). Как отличить, где есть аффиксация а где, наоборот, универбация? Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Аффиксация и универбация - разные способы образования, оба морфологические.

**Аффиксация** (с помощью аффиксов: приставочный, суффиксальный, приставочно-суффиксальный, бессуффиксный) и **сложение** (сложение целых слов, сложение основ, сложение основы с целым словом, слияние основ + суффикс, аббревиация).

**Универбация**(семантическая конденсация) - это способ образования новых слов **на базе устойчивых словосочетаний.** Суть его заключается в устранении диалектического противоречия между формой и содержанием: двучленностью наименования и единством его значения.

**В качестве производящей базы обычно используется не все словосочетание, а лишь основа одного слова.** Как правило, выбирается компонент, в котором содержится основная информация — *тушен(ое) мясо → тушенка, грузов(ой) автомобиль → грузовик, мотор(ная) лодка → моторка*. В процессе образования данных слов участвуют суффиксы с предметным значением (-к-, -ик-) с морфами –уш(к), юш(к), -яш(к) и др.: *однокомнатная квартира → однушка, мультипликационный фильм → мультяшка.* В каждом слове они обозначают тот конкретный предмет, который в базовом сочетании определяется именем существительным.

Образование новых слов путем универбации (семантической конденсации) не является чем-то принципиально новым для русского словообразования. Такая словопроизводственная модель “Литератур(ная газета) + к(а) → Литературка” русскому языку известна давно (сравните: треугольная шляпа → треуголка, касторовое масло → касторка, винтовое ружье → винтовка). Однако в последнее время она особенно активизировалась. Среди слов-неологизмов, собранных в словаре-справочнике “Новые слова и значения” под ред. Н. З. Котеловой очень много слов-универбов.

Назовем некоторые семантические группы слов-универбов:

• названия круп и каш в разговорной речи (манка ‑ манная каша, крупа, гречка, овсянка, перловка и т.д.); продуктов: сгущёнка ‑ консервированное сгущённое молоко с сахаром (надпись на этикетке);

• названия помещений по действию, в них совершаемому, или по лицу работающего в нем (сортировка, дежурка, мойка и т.п.)

• официальных бумаг, документов (пенсионка, сопроводиловка, **зачетка**, т.е. зачетная книжка)

• сокращения наименования в названиях площадей и зданий, больниц и библиотек, выставочных залов (**Таганка**, т.е. Таганская площадь, **Склиф**, т.е.больница им. Склифосовского и т.д.)

Их появление и распространение в языке объясняется стремлением носителей языка к экономии речевых средств. Любое слово-универб является более кратким средством выражения, чем соответствующее ему устойчивое словосочетание.

Продуктивность универбации (семантической конденсации) как способа образования новых слов особенно высока в разговорной речи. Оттуда слова-универбы проникают и в кодифицированный литературный язык.

Источник: https://megaobuchalka.ru/5/41251.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!